# Error downloading and unpacking sample package: Error: spawn ..\Local\Android\SDK ENOENT

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

Help me, when I run: *expo init my-app*

*`error: Error downloading and unpacking sample package: Error: spawn C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\SDK ENOENT × An error occurred while downloading and unzipping the template.`*

I try: *npx create-expo-app myapp*
or: *npm -v*
*also got error: *'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" -g prefix is not recognized receive is an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*
*

I also tried assigning user permissions to the SDK folder and checking the ANDROID_HOME environment variable but it didn't work.
I have uninstalled from: Node, Npm, Expo, Android Studio but it doesn't work.

(Before that I was working normally).
Help me. Thank you very much